# optional parameter in Spring MVC method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning spring MVC and come across these methos in spring   contrller MVC 3.1

```
ControllerClass(){
  @RequestMapping(....)
  public String show( Model uiModel) {

    return ".....";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@Valid Contact contact, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, 
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale,
        @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) Part file) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
           ...........
        return ".....";
    }
```

parameters like BindingResult , Model , 
            HttpServletRequest , RedirectAttributes , Locale ,
            @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) Part are optional but I wonder where I can find these optional  parameter and under which situation it can appear in method.

Comment: It's quite simple: you read the documentation, and they're all described: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-methods.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter:

- `BindingResult` - imagine you have an registration-form and you would pre validate the user input, then you can use the `BindingResult`.
- `Model` - After the user is registered, he wants to edit his own profile he goes to a edit site, in this site you would show the data from the user. Here you can search for the user and add the user-object to the model and in the template you can read the values from the `model`-`attribute`.
- `HttpServletRequest` provides request information.
- `@RequestParam(value="file", required=false)` from Spring:

> annotated parameters for access to specific Servlet request parameters. Parameter values are converted to the declared method argument type

Imagine you have a table of users and you would edit one of these, you select an entry and there you can send the userId as a requestparam.

There is a similar attribute, it's called `@PathVariable` the main difference, the `@PathVariable` is mandatory. The `@RequestParam` is optional respectively for this exist a "fallback/default value". 
The `@PathVariable` is a part from the url:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{login}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editUserByLogin(@PathVariable("login") final String login, final Principal principal) {}
```

The other two I have not used yet.